# Highlight a table cell when selecting a row

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I want to highlight a table cell (`td`) instead of the entire row when a particular row is clicked.

This code below highlights a row in yellow. I would like to highlight the `Name` column when the row is selected instead.

```
$(function() {
    Thing = function(id, name, selected) {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = id, 
        self.Name = name, 
        self.isSelected = ko.computed(function() {
            return selected() === self;
        });
    };

    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.model = {};
        self.model.CurrentDisplayThing = ko.observable();
        self.model.Things = ko.observableArray(
            [
                new Thing(1, "Thing 1", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing),
                new Thing(2, "Thing 2", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing),
                new Thing(3, "Thing 3", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing)
            ]);
        self.selectThing = function(item) {
            self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
        };
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/6FCEe/)

Comment: Remove css from table row and provide it in td <td data-bind="text: Name,css: { selected: isSelected}"></td> http://jsfiddle.net/6FCEe/193/

Comment: @RohithNair that's what my answer already says.

Comment: @tanner I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your css `data-binding` to the `td` level instead of the `tr` level:

### [Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FCEe/176/)

Your old code:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $root.selectThing, css: { selected: isSelected } ">
    <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
</tr>
```

Becomes:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $root.selectThing ">
    <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: Name, css: { selected: isSelected }"></td>
</tr>
```

Also runs in Stack Snippet below with latest version of Knockout, so it doesn't appear to be a versioning issue based on your comment.

```js
$(function() {
    Thing = function(id, name, selected) {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = id, 
        self.Name = name, 
        self.isSelected = ko.computed(function() {
            return selected() === self;
        });
    };

    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.model = {};
        self.model.CurrentDisplayThing = ko.observable();
        self.model.Things = ko.observableArray(
            [
                new Thing(1, "Thing 1", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing),
                new Thing(2, "Thing 2", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing),
                new Thing(3, "Thing 3", self.model.CurrentDisplayThing)
            ]);
        self.selectThing = function(item) {
            self.model.CurrentDisplayThing(item);
        };
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

```css
.selected { background-color: yellow; }
thead tr {
    border:1px solid black;
    background:lightgray;
}tbody tr {
    border:1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="if:model.CurrentDisplayThing">
    Display: <span data-bind="text: model.CurrentDisplayThing().ID"></span>
</div>
<table class="defaultGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.Things">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectThing ">
            <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name, css: { selected: isSelected}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: @Happy the fiddle works fine, is there some other code you have locally that you haven't shown?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
    tbody tr.selected > td:last-child{
       background-color: yellow;
    }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6FCEe/172/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it works.

```
<table id="tableID" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr >
            <td >1</td>
            <td >2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

javaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";  
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the follwing code can help you:

```
$("table > thead > tr > th").css({"background":"#D3D3D3"});
$("table > thead > tr :nth-child("+($(this).index() + 1) +")").css({"background":"RED"});
```